# TypeScript Extend Prototype not working when import other extend prototype

Tags: typescript, prototype

Excuse my English, I have a String and Date extension, everything worked correctly until I wanted to use a property of my string extension in my date extension, I have searched and I have not found anything in forums, has it happened to someone?

==========================================

```
import './string.extension';

type IntervalDateDiff = 'days' | 'months' | 'years' | 'hours' | 'minutes';

interface Date {
    dateDiff(dateStart: Date, intervalo: IntervalDateDiff): number,
    format(): string,
    formatTime(): string,
    onlyDate(): Date,
    newDate(date: string): Date
}

Date.prototype.dateDiff = function (dateStart: Date, intervalo: IntervalDateDiff): number {
    const dateEnd: Date = this;
    const miliseconds = dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime();

    let intervaloTiempo = 0;
    switch (intervalo) {
        case 'minutes':
            intervaloTiempo = 1000*60;
            break;
        case 'hours':
            intervaloTiempo = 1000*60*60;
            break;
        case 'days':
            intervaloTiempo = 1000*60*60*24;
            break;
        case 'months':
            intervaloTiempo = 1000*60*60*30.417;
            break;
        case 'years':
            intervaloTiempo = 1000*60*60*30.417*12;
            break;
    }

    return miliseconds / intervaloTiempo;
}

Date.prototype.newDate = function (date: string): Date {
    date = date.left(10);
    
    const year = +(date.left(4));
    const month = +(date.substring(6, 2));
    const day = +(date.right(2));

    return new Date(year, month + 1, day);
}
```

The errors are as follows:
Property 'dateDiff' does not exist on type 'Date'.
Property 'newDate' does not exist on type 'Date'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a globally available type, you need to put those additions in `declare global {}` block.

```
declare global {
  interface Date {
    dateDiff(dateStart: Date, intervalo: IntervalDateDiff): number,
    format(): string,
    formatTime(): string,
    onlyDate(): Date,
    newDate(date: string): Date
  }
}
```

This is required because by default, types are local to the file they are declared in. But you are modifying a globally available object, so typescript needs to know that you mean to modify the global values, and that you know the changes are expected in the global scope.

With this change, typescript will allow you to extend the prototype of the global object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgHQHoDOMrAHYHMkCmAHjAdmsBNggNwBQdMAnmAXAJLalQBuAhgBsAIn1JDgAMwlwAvIgAmfJmgRwAPohBUYACxXrETAnyj6NCHRACup1eZA4rpFfTryCAYwEm2uARAAjQTgAbzo4OBxuCT4PNhFSUPCIuEUxSQkACjSCAGUYExgALjgEggAaSK4CXkEIEs5ufmFRAnEpAEoS7CsQAJry5IiJaBBRTK64DCw8QZS4EagxmAAVUAIJkumcXDmUqgEmMs3S1r2I7AIAd2OcrcwdybLkgF86N7oypDAoCBg-lgEJA5drSOQSKzYDwwSjYODZVr5QolMqVKI1Zr1DjVWotdKdbq9fpQJLzDxUDCpVoAUWw8hRrVkcF0wDQ9DJFPgDgErM8VHkaCZOVp8iQuAIq3WEzgAFoqaQkbAxRK1iANh1XPMBBKqk06msCOAIEyAAzslJoK7AGAeHTw9G4iAdUnzFIePhoNgIBw9ZwIIpDV3zB2Yg1GpkARhN0YAVAA2M2BoMRAJQYwAa3NQfdnsQlhsKgDyddIf1wENkEj0ZN8ZrCazxbgqYzDbJHq9imU-qTydL-jDlbkUdjCdrMYATAAWVvJ5t8TM9iI5r1aLh6buNlJ9iAD41D6tj0cAZhNSEnEYA7DOg3OF8Xl4ZjLYi5vdRiyxW93Bh3XfzGT2el4xhG47Xq6t4Nh88xpjANhwtyvLknSgooG+jq7vQHxfD8fwAqwSCXDcjLgpC0KwvCdxTA8eBPIyYTzDkQqtEg2oSDAmRRhqgaBkhlJGCYTIANQIqQLEEGxmSTh0XEcuQXLaHacjCTkSBoFYATbHgmRxpU47SQ2vHwJ2QkiUCWC4Do7F6VxgYwXBcCEacpCZPxUCVKuuhwIJ36VJ2XEvEAA)